# Unresolved reference on setContent() while migrating to Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

`setContent()` is giving me an unresolved reference when using the code in [the tutorial](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/migrate). It's strange because the compiler is recognizing `setContent()` (or it wouldn't be giving the helper error). I'm unsure why this is not building.

Other similar questions on Stack Overflow didn't answer this one.

```
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent

class MyClass {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent { // Unresolved reference -- None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch
            Text(text = "My app")
        }
    }
}
```

```
// gradle (copied from Android docs)
dependencies {
    def composeBom = platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.10.00')
    implementation composeBom
    androidTestImplementation composeBom

    // Choose one of the following:
    // Material Design 3
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    // or Material Design 2
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material'
    // or skip Material Design and build directly on top of foundational components
    implementation 'androidx.compose.foundation:foundation'
    // or only import the main APIs for the underlying toolkit systems,
    // such as input and measurement/layout
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'

    // Android Studio Preview support
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'

    // UI Tests
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'

    // Optional - Included automatically by material, only add when you need
    // the icons but not the material library (e.g. when using Material3 or a
    // custom design system based on Foundation)
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core'
    // Optional - Add full set of material icons
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended'
    // Optional - Add window size utils
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class'

    // Optional - Integration with activities
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.0'
    // Optional - Integration with ViewModels
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.1'
    // Optional - Integration with LiveData
    implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata'
    // Optional - Integration with RxJava
    implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-rxjava2'

    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: What class does your `MyClass` extend? Your code has it not extending anything, so there's no `onCreate` method in the first place.

Comment: Yep, good call. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`androidx.activity.compose.setContent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/compose/package-summary?hl=en#(androidx.activity.ComponentActivity).setContent(androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionContext,kotlin.Function0)) is defined as an extension method on `ComponentActivity`, so make sure you're calling it from (or at least on) an Activity subclass that extends ComponentActivity:

```kotlin
class MyClass: ComponentActivity() {
```

Comment: Yep, that was it! Thanks!